# I have to read 10 values entered by the user into an array, then print them in C

Tags: c, arrays

My teacher gave us code that is supposed to prompt the user to enter 10 numbers, call a function to sort the array from smallest to largest, then print the result. All we had to do is read the input and print it out. This is what she gave us:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define num 10

void sort_array(int *a, int b);

int main(void)

{

    int array[num] = {0}, i;



    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Please enter %d integers ", num);
    /* read the input! */

    sort_array(a, num);

    /* print the sorted array */

return 0;

}

void sort_array(int *a, int b)

{

bool swapped = true;
int temp, i, j = 0;

while (swapped)
    {
    swapped  = false;
    j++;
    for (i = 0; i < b - 1; i +1)

        { 
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a [i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
                }

            }

        }
}
```

This is my attempt at it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define num 10

void sort_array(int *a, int b);

int main(void)

{

int array[num] = {0}, i, j;

printf("Please enter %d integers: ", num);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

/* read the input! */

sort_array(array, num);

/* print the array */
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

return 0;

}

void sort_array(int *a, int b)

{

bool swapped = true;
int temp, i, j = 0;

while (swapped)
    {
    swapped  = false;
    j++;
    for (i = 0; i < b - 1; i +1)

        { 
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
                }

            }

        }
}
```

I know I'm probably pretty far from being right, but could someone please help me out? I'm using Quincy to compile. The program will let me input the numbers, but I have to shut the program down with ctrl+c.

Sorry if I messed up the formatting.

Comment: Did your program not work correctly? If so, please tell what makes you think that?

Comment: Sorry, just edited. The program will let me input the numbers, but won't do anything else.

Comment: You have a typo in `for (i = 0; i < b - 1; i +1)`. It needs to be `for (i = 0; i < b - 1; ++i)`.

Comment: lol thank you so much. I never would have checked that. It works like a charm now!

Comment: Voting to close for typo.

Comment: She's program cannot compile. :D

Comment: how do you mark it as answered? I don't want anyone wasting their time on an answered question.

Comment: @JohnD., when a problem can be fixed by fixing a typo, it's best to delete the post. Such questions don't add any long term value to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are programming in C, is it very good practice debug using `printf`

I re-write your code, with the right correction to make it work..and also include some prints to show you in my point of view, how could you debug..

Do not forget to remove all unnecessary prints to submit the program to your teacher

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define num 10

void sort_array(int *a, int b);

int main(void)

{

int array[num] = {0}, i, j;

printf("Please enter %d integers:\n", num);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("number %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

/* read the input! */

sort_array(array, num);

/* print the array */
printf("Sorted Array: [");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
printf("]");

return 0;

}

void sort_array(int *a, int b)

{

bool swapped = true;
int temp, i, j = 0;

while (swapped)
    {
    swapped  = false;
    j++;
    for (i = 0; i < b - 1; i ++)

        { 
            printf("i:%d --- A[i] = %d ---- A[i+1] = %d\n", i, a[i], a[i+1]);
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
                }

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `qsort` in `stdlib.h` (guaranteed to be much more well tested than your *roll-your-own* sorting scheme...)

Comment: Because we haven't gotten that far in the book. I read ahead a little and I know you can do it, but I don't want her to think I'm "cheating" lol.